# Init count loop variable out or inside the loop declaration in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, performance, loops

Maybe is a silly question, but I wonder if affects or not in the performance of a loop the declaration of the loop's counter (int i = 0 or size_t i = 0) inside or out the loop. For example:

```
// Declaration of counter out of the loop:
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    // do something
}

// Declaration of counter inside of the loop:
for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

I understand that the compiler creates internally the counter variable only one time in both cases, thus, is not any difference... right?

Comment: Your compiler has an option that produces assembly listing of compiled code. Have you tried compiling both versions, and then see if the compiler produces same or different code?

Comment: No, I'm not checked the assembler code generated in both versions... Good point. I'm going to check by myself and will post the traces. I'm working with OpenCL that is similar to C99, so I guess will be similars the traces of C and OpenCL

Comment: Really handy tool to quickly see how code is transformed by different compilers and compiler options: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Also don't get fooled into thinking shorter code is faster code. Usually it is, but very simple-looking, short code could do stuff that the CPU hates to do, like abuse the cache with a poor memory access pattern, and winds up taking much, much longer than a program doing the same job the long way. Strive for simple and worry about fast only after simple is proven too slow.

Comment: one very important consideration is the 'scope' of a variable.  The goal is to minimize the 'scope'  One way to do that is: `for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {`  the other way, as demonstrated in your sample code, results in the 'scope' of the variable being all the file following the declaration of the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good modern compilers with optimization enabled generate code based on where an identifier is used regardless of where it is declared (subject to the semantics required by the C standard or other rules). This should include redundant initializations; the compiler should recognize that the actual effects involving `i` are that it needs to be initialized before the loop starts (and does not need to be initialized earlier), that it is used in the loop, and that it is not used after the loop (unless it is used in code not shown in the question).

So there will be no performance difference in such circumstances.

There is a difference in how the code affects and interacts with humans. The further an identifier is declared from where it is used, the more opportunity there is for a mistake to be made in code in between. To reduce bugs, declare an  identifier just where you need it and seek to limit its scope to just the span of code where it is needed.

Additionally, the more distance there is between declaration and use, the harder it is for humans to comprehend source code as it grows complex. So, to help people understand, modify, and debug your source code in the future, limit the scope of identifiers.

(There are some exceptions to this. For example, this rule would have you declare external functions just inside functions where they are used. But function declarations are commonly placed outside of any other functions. There is some benefit to this: If a function is declared outside any function and is also defined in the same source file, then the declaration is visible where the definition occurs, and the compiler will provide a warning or error message if they disagree, thus catching a mistake. If the function is not defined in the same file, then generally its declaration should be provided by a header file, and header files should generally be included, with `#include` directives, outside of any function, in part because they may contain other declarations that are inappropriate inside a function.)